# Word order in Spanish

Tags: gramática, orden-de-palabras

The sentence I need to translate is this:

*Your threats are never going to frighten me.*

However, I am still not sure of the most appropriate word-order in Spanish and have ended up with the below three attempts:

**Nunca me van a asustar tus amenazas.**

**Tus amenazas me van a asustar nunca.**

**Tus amenazas nunca me van a asustar.**

Even if all of them are correct grammatically, I would still like to know which of those constructs are most likely to be heard in a real-life conversation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely to be heard:

1) Nunca me van a dar miedo tus amenazas. ("frighten" is a deeper kind of fear than "scare")

2) Nunca me van a asustar tus amenazas. (A threat doesn't surprise-scare you, it frightens you.)

3) Tus amenazas nunca me van a dar miedo.

4) Tus amenazas nunca me van a asustar.

...

109992) Tus amenazas me van a asustar nunca.

Comment: Plus, for 109992 the correct sentence would be "Tus amenazas no me van a asustar nunca". The "no" is necessary.

Comment: No, it can happen, but you'll hear it about once every two lifetimes. Most likely in a soap opera, and it would sound like this: "Tus amenazas, me van a asustar: nunca".

Answer (score 1):

De las tres opciones la más común es la tercera:

**Tus amenazas nunca me van a asustar.**

La primera opción también es común:

**Nunca me van a asustar tus amenazas.**

La que menos se utilizaría y hasta se escucha raro es:

**Tus amenazas me van a asustar nunca.**